# How to efficiently compare Sets in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to compare two sets using the `equal` algorithm but it's giving me an error.
How is it possible to know if two sets are equal or not?

```
if(equal (a.begin(), a.end(), v.begin(), v.end())
```

Answer (score 12):

You can simply say `a == v`, <del>or perhaps `a.size() == v.size() && a == v`</del>. It's as efficient as it can be. <del>(The latter form with the explicit size check may be better because set iterators aren't random-access.)</del> Update: The size check is implied [thanks @juanchopanza!]

Comment: I would hesitate in saying that `a == b` is as fast/efficient as possible, as it may or may not do extra comparisons behind the scenes. Without knowing the implementation, you cannot say that it's the 'fastest' out there.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: But we know the implementation, since it's specified.

Comment: I thought that the implementation itself isn't specified, only the behavior, correct? Different STL implementations may differ.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: It's specified in terms of `std::equal`, whose complexity and actual number of comparisons in turn are specified.

Comment: Then you *don't* know that it is as fast as possible. `std::equal` is very naive in it's implementation - chances are, there are micro-optimizations that could be made for a certain STL implementation if you really cared.

Comment: Interesting. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator_cmp) seems to imply a size check is done first. That could be wrong, of course.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Oh, that's entirely possible. I was hoping that would be true, though I wasn't totally sure. Thanks.

Comment: Note that I haven't cross-checked against the standard. And my beer won't allow me to do it now.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Nah, this sounds very familiar, so I'm sure you're right. We've had this question before. Thanks!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: containers `==` is defined as _semantically equal to_ `distance(a.begin(), a.end()) == distance(b.begin(), b.end()) && equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin())`.  That's very different than "implemented as".

Comment: I just noticed that my tree structure that I wrote _is_ implemented as `std::equal`.  Whoops!  Im going to go fix that now...

Comment: Of course an implementation *could* implement a less efficient algorithm than the one used for describing the semantics, as long as the complexity is also the same. But then, the compiler could also insert a five second do-nothing loop after each statement. At some point, you just have to assume the compiler implementer is not a complete moron (or otherwise, switch the compiler).

Answer (score 5):

You are likely invoking the [`std::equal` overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) taking 3 iterators and an additional predicate. So just leave away the second end, since it isn't interpreted as an end iterator, but a predicate, which is rubbish:

```
std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), v.begin())
```

But as *Mark* ammends in his comment in this case you have to make sure that both containers' sizes match beforehand, otherwise you go the risk of running over the end of the second set. Note that C++14 will indeed introduce a `std::equal` overload taking four iterators (which is what you intended) and which will preform the size check implicitly, but it seems your implementation doesn't support this yet.

Other than that the other answers and comments are correct in that `a == v` is much simpler, clearer and more streamlined.

Comment: Note that if you use `std::equal` you'll also need to check first if the containers are the same size, otherwise you might run off the end of the second one.